# How do I read the value of Outlook RecurrencePattern.DayOfWeekMask?

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto

I have what I hope is an easy question. I need to be able (in an Outlook VSTO programmed in VB.NET) to read the value of an appointment item's RecurrencePattern.DayOfWeekMask property. All examples I've found online just show how to write to that property, not read it. The documentation kindasorta indicates that it returns a kind of Enum(?), but

```
Dim aptItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem = TryCast(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem, Outlook.AppointmentItem)

...

Dim oRecurrencePattern As Outlook.RecurrencePattern = aptItem.GetRecurrencePattern
For Each i In System.Enum.GetValues(oRecurrencePattern.DayOfWeekMask)
```

returns an error, stating that they can't convert it into a Type.

I'm a bit at a loss as to what else to try. Many thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score -1):

DayOfWeekMask is an int. You need to use bitwise "and" (&) operator to test days:

```
if ((oRecurrencePattern.DayOfWeekMask & OlDaysOfWeek.olMonday) != 0)
{
    //the appointment occurs on Monday
}
```